# Choppy slow animation when opening Show Applications (launcher) on Ubuntu 20.04 on VMware VM

Tags: gnome, 20.04, ubuntu-gnome, animations

I have updated my Ubuntu VMware vm from 18.04 to 20.04 yesterday and everything is working fine, except the animation for the launcher, which is really choppy.

If I turn on Zoom in universal access and set it to 1, then the animation works flawlessly.

[Here is a screen recording with no zoom vs 1x zoom (imgur link)](https://i.imgur.com/FRumzLQ.mp4)

I have not noticed any other issues with animations anywhere else, not any issues playing video.

I have `Fractional Scaling` off.

I am not having this issue if I select `Ubuntu On Wayland` when logging in. I did not have this issue on 18.04.

Output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`:

```
VGA compatible controller: VMware SVGA II Adapter
Subsystem: VMware SVGA II Adapter
Kernel driver in use: vmwgfx
Kernel modules: vmwgfx
```

This is [the configuration (imgur link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiwmI.png) I have for this VM (it also has 1 gb of video memory, but even if I set it to 2gb the launcher animation is still choppy):

Do you have any idea what might be causing this choppy animation only for the launcher?

Thank you!

P.S.: my reputation is too low to post images, that is why I have added hyperlinks to Imgur

Answer (score 2):

I switched from Xorg to Wayland and the issue was solved

Comment: Do you mean you switched from Wayland to Xorg? That is the solution proposed in another answer. your answer proposes exactly the opposite. Please explain your answer in some more detail.

Comment: Yes, I did the opposite as the previous answer suggested and this solved my problem

Comment: solved my problem too. Thank you :)

Comment: switching to wayland is painful on nvidia. I did it but cpu usage was so high, and it was so laggy, even worse than before. I did `apt remove xserver-xorg-video-intel` and now it's way more smooth!

Answer (score 0):

You should try to log in Xorg instead, in case you are on Wayland (log out, press the settings button on the bottom right and select Xorg).

This should solve the problem.